# How to return data in loop for WP REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

```
function getProgramTourInfoByID(){

            $data = getProgramTourInfoByCate();
            //print_r($data);

            foreach ($data  as $key => $id) {

                //echo( $id);
                    $count =0;
                while( have_rows('package_scd',  $id ) ): the_row(); 
                    //if(get_sub_field('start_date') != null){
                    //echo $id."\r\n";

                    $array[$count]  = array(
                    'id'    =>  $id , 
                    'title' =>  get_the_title($id),
                    'url'   =>  get_the_permalink($id),
                    'start' =>  get_sub_field('start_date'),
                    'end'   =>  get_sub_field('end_date'),
                    'price_single_room' => get_sub_field('price_single_room'),
                    'price_adult' =>  get_sub_field('price_adult'),
                    'type'  =>  "restricted",

                    );


                    $count ++; 
                endwhile; 



            }

            $output  = array('sourcename' => $array );

    return  $output;              
}


function getProgramTourInfoByCate(){
          $term_id = 3;
          $args  = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'package'),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => array('publish') , 
            'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'tour-categories',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $term_id,
                        'order'=>'DESC',
                        'orderby'=>'menu_order',
                      )
                    )
              );

              $query = new WP_Query($args);

              if($query->have_posts()): 

                while($query->have_posts()): 
                    $query->the_post();

                        $arr[] = get_the_ID();

                endwhile;

            return $arr; 

            endif;
}
```

Here is my code but it is return the wrong output. When I test `echo $id` in loop `while( have_rows('package_scd',  $id ) ): the_row()` there is return all of the ID from database it is the right output:

[image]

but when I have return `$output  = array('sourcename' => $array )`. There is return only two ID (24930 and 18367) I am not sure why the rest of ID are not coming.

[image]

Comment: print the `$array` value inside the while loop and check..

Comment: I have print_r($array[$count]); it is return all of data as I wanted.
but  when I  return $output  = array('sourcename' => $array );  There is return only two ID (24930 and 18367) .

Comment: did you try with `$output  = json-encode(array('sourcename' => $array );)`?

Comment: yes , but return the same output.

Comment: I think no issue in your code.. above the code only you are using in file also or here edited code?

Comment: Now it working I fix it by use  $output[] = $array[$count];
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

May be its overwrite $array keys..
Declare,

```
$count = 0;
$array = array();
```

before foreach loop starts.
 I am sure, this will work.